# Proof: If event $A_1,\ldots,A_n$ are independent then their indicators are independent

Tags: measure-theory

Comes from Alan F. Karr Probability textbook page 81
$$
\prod\limits_{i\in I} P(A_i) \times \prod\limits_{j\notin J} [1-P(A_j]-\prod\limits_{i\in J} (P(A_j) \times \prod\limits_{j\notin J}[1-P(A_j)]
=\prod\limits_{i\in I} P(A_i)\times \prod\limits_{j\notin I} [1-P(A_j]
$$

where $J=I+\{j_0\}$ and $j_0 \in I^c$ This comes from the theorem that $A_1,\ldots,A_n$ event are independent if their indicators are independent. I do not understand how their simplify the equation from left side expression to right side expression. It seems that the term they are subtracting is equal to zero and then they change the product limits.

Comment: Hii, Don, how are you? Sorry because I'm asking this here. Did you find any manual solution of Alan Karr's book of probability? If yes, let me know please, and I will send you my email. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that
$$ j \not \in J \implies j \in J^c = ( I + \{j_0 \} )^c = I^c \setminus \{ j_0\}$$
Thus we have
$$ \prod_{i \in J} P(A_i) = P(A_{j_0} ) \prod_{ i \in I} P(A_i) $$
$$ \prod _{ j \not \in J} [1 - P( A_{j}) ] =\prod _{ j  \in J^c} [1 - P( A_{j}) ] = \frac{1}{1 - P(A_{j_0}) }\prod_{j \in I^c}[1 - P( A_{j}) ] = \frac{1}{1 - P(A_{j_0}) }\prod_{j \not \in I}[1 - P( A_{j}) ]$$
Using the above equalities we see
$$\prod_{i \in I} P(A_i) \prod _{ j \not \in J} [1 - P( A_{j}) ]  -\prod_{i \in J} P(A_i) \prod _{ j \not \in J} [1 - P( A_{j}) ] = $$
$$ = \frac{1}{1-P(A_{j_0})}\prod_{i \in I} P(A_i) \prod _{ j \not \in I} [1 - P( A_{j}) ]  -\frac{ P(A_{j_0})}{1 - P( A_{j_0})}\prod_{i \in I} P(A_i) \prod _{ j \not \in I} [1 - P( A_{j}) ] $$
$$=\prod_{i \in I} P(A_i) \prod _{ j \not \in I} [1 - P( A_{j}) ]  $$

Comment: Makes so much sense. Was thinking way too hard... Thank you.